# neo4j, how to query chain using two different nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j graph: (person)-[like]-(fruit). I want to find person of person of person recursively using [like] and (fruit).

For example,

(John)-[like]->(Apple)<-[like]-(Sam)->[like]-(Banana)<-[like]-(Jack)-[like]->(Grape)<-[like]-(Lisa)...

How can I query this relationship using the neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence in your path is always a repetition of person, fruit, person ... and assuming only people like fruit and not the other way round, you could use a [quantified path pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#quantified-path-patterns) like this:

```cypher
MATCH p = ((:Person)-[:like]->(:Fruit)<-[:like]-(:Person))+
RETURN p
```

If you want the paths to start at a particular person e.g. `'John'`, anchor the start node like so:

```cypher
MATCH p = (:Person {name: 'John'}) 
          ((:Person)-[:like]->(:Fruit)<-[:like]-(:Person))+
RETURN p
```

If you want to include paths where only one person likes a fruit, use a `UNION`:

```cypher
MATCH p = ((:Person)-[:like]->(:Fruit)<-[:like]-(:Person))+
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH p = (:Person)-[:like]->(:Fruit) 
RETURN p
```

Note that some results may be subpaths of other results.

If you are using a version < 5.9 *and* have APOC installed, you can specify a sequence of labels and relationship types in the configuration of `apoc.path.expandConfig`. This returns paths that start at `'John'`:

```cypher
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'John'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(p, {
    sequence: 'Person, like>, Fruit, <like, >Person'
})
YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Comment: You should probably modify the second `MATCH` in the `UNION` example to only include fruits with a single incoming `like`: `MATCH p = (:Person)-[:like]->(f:Fruit) WHERE COUNT{ ()-[:like]->(f) } = 1`.

Comment: True enough. But I decided to keep it readable and just note that there will be subpaths of other results, including those from the second arm of the UNION.